# Upgrading ASA and ASDM on a ASA5510

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I have a single Cisco ASA 5510 in production.

It has:

- ASA version `8.0(2)`
- ASDM version `6.0(2)`
- 1GB RAM (upgraded recently from 256MB)
- 64MB Flash

I have backed up the flash and the configuration.

We need to upgrade the ASA version to `9.1(4)` and ASDM version to `7.1(5)`

I have the following queries:

1. Do I need to upgrade the Flash from 64MB to a larger one for the software upgrade?
2. What is the recommended upgrade path from `8.0(2)` to `9.1(4)`?
3. Do I need to manually update the start-up configuration due to changes in NAT syntax etc between these versions or will this be done automatically if I follow a recomended upgrade path?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It should "automagicly" convert the configuration, but be prepared for it to completely booger it up. If you haven't been studying the "new" syntax, it'll drive you crazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It is recommended you upgrade the flash to at least the current shipping default of 256mb in the fine print (number 11) of the 8.3 memory upgrade guide. (http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/hw/maintenance/guide/asa_hw/overview.html#pgfId-1054519). The same would apply for 9.1. The concern would come with loading the ASA code it self, along with ASDM and AnyConnect.
2. As for the upgrade path you can find the recommended path in the release notes for 9.1

   - "You cannot upgrade directly to 9.0 or later. You must first upgrade to Version 8.3 or 8.4 for a successful migration." http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa91/release/notes/asarn91.html
3. There are provisions to migrate the old NAT config to the new NAT config however we have seen in the past they may not be the most accurate, however your mileage may vary depending on the complexity of your configuration. This would occur the 8.3 to 8.4 portion of the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for a clear answer addressing all points. Regarding point (2), since we are on ASA 8.0(2), what would be the upgrade path from this to Version 8.3 or 8.4? And regarding point (3) are there any ways to convert the old NAT config using any online tools (or anything similar)?